# How to read a string from keyboard on the same line with output?

Tags: string, io, rust

I'm reading a string like this:

```
print!("Input string: "); 

let string: String = String::new();
std::io::stdin().read_line(&mut string);
```

When I launch the program I see:

```
(write a string here)
Input string:
```

But I need:

```
Input string: (write a string here)
```

How to implement this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Add a call to `stdout().flush()` to force the buffer to output before `read_line` is called:

```
fn main() {
   print!("Input string: "); 
   std::io::stdout().flush();
   let mut string: String = String::new();
   std::io::stdin().read_line(&mut string);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer is correct: you need to call `stdout().flush()` before `read_line`. However the code won't compile on Rust 1.6.0. The following changes will make it compile. They also show how to use the resulting string:

```
use std::io::prelude::*;
use std::io;

fn main() {
    print!("Input string: ");
    io::stdout().flush().ok().expect("Could not flush stdout");
    let mut string: String = String::new();
    let _ = std::io::stdin().read_line(&mut string);
    println!("{}", string.trim());
}
```